# How to deploy Library contract separate from the main contract and link it

Tags: remix, library, compiler

For deployment I am using remix. When I deploy `Hello.sol` the compiler typically merges `SafeMath.sol` as a part of the main contract (`Hello.sol`) and deploys. This adds up library and main contract's deployment cost as whole. I want to do this operation separately in order to divide deployment cost in to multiple operations.

**[Q]** Is there any way to first deploy the library contract separately from the main contract and than link it to the main contract on `remix`? Should I use `Truffle` or follow different approach for this?

I have following simple contract, `remix` deploys `Hello.sol` as as single contract which also includes `SafeMath.sol`:

SafeMath.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "addition overflow");

        return c;
    }
}
```

---

Hello.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Hello {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint value;

    constructor() public
    {
        value = value.add(100);
    }    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Remix does this automatically.

Library code:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

library Foo {
    struct F {
        uint256 x;
    }

    function foo (F storage f) external {
        f.x = 123456789;
    }
}
```

Main contract code:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

import './Foo.sol';

contract Bar {
    Foo.F public f;

    function bar () public {
        Foo.foo (f);
    }
}
```

When I tell Remix to deploy `Bar` contract, it actually executes two separate transactions: the first to deploy `Foo` library and the second to deploy `Bar` contract linked to the `Foo` library:

[image]

Though this way you cannot link library that is already deployed.

Comment: Why the same approach does not work on the code piece that I shared on my question, where remix does not separate contract and library? In order to deploy Library separately should it has its own storage? @Mikhail Vladimirov

Comment: This is because you call `internal` function from the library, and `internal` functions cannot be called externally, so compiler had no other option than to embed the function into calling smart contract.

Comment: If I replace the `interval` keyword with `public` and keep those previously `internal` functions in the Library, will those cause additional gas usage? @Mikhail Vladimirov

Comment: It is a tradeoff.  Internal functions are cheaper to call but increase deployment cost of the contract.  External library functions are more expensive to call, but allow to keep byte code size and deployment cost lower.

Comment: I assume external can only be called as though it's calling another contract or library, so additional 2,000 gas for the jump @Mikhail Vladimirov

Answer (score 1):

in truffle you can do something like this:

```
const ConvertLib = artifacts.require("ConvertLib");
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ConvertLib);
  deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin);
  deployer.deploy(MetaCoin);
};
```

from

https://github.com/truffle-box/metacoin-box/blob/master/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

I'm not aware if that is possible with remix :/

Comment: Remix will just go ahead and link the contracts so contracts with libraries work when using the JavsScript VM. I suspect the process works with Injected Web3 but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I deployed the library as contract (and also change the function to `public`) and linked the “contract-library” like this `SafeMath safeMath = SafeMath(0xF2fD4E3A5b94f0B4D8EE74C009E12F698906420b);`.

Here is the code of the contract **Hello**:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256);
}

contract Hello {
    SafeMath safeMath = SafeMath(0xF2fD4E3A5b94f0B4D8EE74C009E12F698906420b);

    uint public value;

    constructor() public
    {
        value = safeMath.add(value, 100);
    }    
}
```

(Technically I think it’s a solution for your issue but it’s not very elegant.)

See https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x031c90e551c760c895cdf7d14e940e83578f9cc0#code for the contract.
And see https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xF2fD4E3A5b94f0B4D8EE74C009E12F698906420b#code for the “contract-library”.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue before, and finally got it work like this

```
const ConvertLib = artifacts.require("ConvertLib");
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  ConvertLib.address = "0xabce987676...";
  deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin);
  deployer.deploy(MetaCoin);
};
```